# creating table into the Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Actually i am creating a Modal and in the modal some dynamic data is to shown but my problem is while i insert the Modal body through the .html tag, I am unable to iterate my object Array into the .html tag,

Here is my Script:

```
  echo "<script>
function myFunction(order){
$('.modal-body').html('<table>'
+'<tr>'

+'<th>'+'<b>S.No</b>'+'</th>'
+'<th>'+'<b>Name</b>'+'</th>'
+'<th>'+'<b>Quantity</b>'+'</th>'
+'<th>'+'<b>Personalization</b>'+'</th>'

  +'</tr>'
   +'<tr>'
      var myOrder = order;    //Here is my problem i want to iterate my Order object here and populate the rows through this
      var arrayLength = myOrder.length;  

+'<td>'+'Bill Gates'+'</td>'
+'<td>'+'555 77 854'+'</td>'
+'<td>'+'Bill Gates'+'</td>'
+'<td>'+'555 77 854'+'</td>'
+'</tr>'
+'</table>');
$('#myModal').modal({backdrop: false}); 
}
</script>";
```

Here is My Modal:

```
      //<!-- Modal -->
   echo"<div class='modal fade' id='myModal' role='dialog'>";
    echo"<div class='modal-dialog'>";

   //    <!-- Modal content-->

     echo"<div class='modal-content'>";
      echo"<div class='modal-header'>";
      echo"<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal'>&times;
    </button>";
      echo"<h4 class='modal-title'><center>Order Details</center></h4>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='modal-body'>";

     // echo "Order Number : " . "<script> ('.modal-body').html(order.order_id) </script>" ."<br>";

    echo"</div>";
    echo"<div class='modal-footer'>";
      echo"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>";
      echo"<button type='button' class='btn btn-default' >Update</button>";
   echo"</div>";
  echo"</div>";

   echo"</div>";
   echo"</div>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want something like

```
function myFunction(order) {
    var result = '<table>' // + '<tr>'... etc

    order.items.forEach(function(entry) {
        result += '<tr>'
                  + '<td>' + order.order_id + '</td>'  // Or whatever field is "S. no"
                  + '<td>' + entry.title + '</td>'
                  + '<td>' + entry.quantity + '</td>'
                  + '<td>' + (entry.personalization || '') + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
    })

    result += '</table>';
    $('.modal-body').html(result);
}
```

In the line where you have `var myOrder = order`. On the other hand, the `order` object only has one `order_id` so it will be the same for everything.

Also this file doesn't need to change so you don't need to *echo scape* it but serve as javascript or inside `<script>` tag.

Comment: Also you don't need `myOrder` and `arrayLength` if that reply is a solution for you.

Comment: Actually i will explain my code little bit, first i create the array of an objects($newOrder[] array) where order is an object and after that in each object i store some variables and one or more array's, so i have to display my array in the Modal Table

Comment: Can you post sample data about what you pass when you call `myFunction`?

Comment: Yes Sir,
**Data is :**
{ "order_id": "45", "uid": "7", "created_date": "2015-12-29", "status": "delivered", "items": [ { "title": "Thar Ke Papad", "quantity": "1", "personalization": null }, { "title": "Thar Ke Papad", "quantity": "1", "personalization": null } ] }

Comment: Now i am struck at point is it possible to insert the SQL query into the javascript........
it means in my project i created a Modal and in the Modal i added a button and as the button is click i have to send a query to my Database.....(the whole work is done through JavaScript)
is it possible or should i use onclick handler in my php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114253/discussion-between-david-gonzalez-and-dhruv-tyagi).

Answer (score 1):

Use like this. if you use plus and single quotes script will not work.

```
echo "<script>
        function myFunction(order){
            $('.modal-body').html(<table>\
            <tr>\
            <th><b>S.No</b></th>\
            <th><b>Name</b></th>\
            <th><b>Quantity</b></th>\
            <th><b>Personalization</b></th>\
              </tr>\
               <tr>\
            <td>Bill Gates</td>\
            <td>555 77 854</td>\
            <td>Bill Gates</td>\
            <td>555 77 854</td>\
            </tr>\
            </table>);
            $(#myModal).modal({backdrop: false}); 
        }
        </script>";
```

Update php variable inside like this..

```
echo "<script>
        function myFunction(order){
            $('.modal-body').html(<table>\
            <tr>\
            <th><b>S.No</b></th>\
            <th><b>Name</b></th>\
            <th><b>Quantity</b></th>\
            <th><b>Personalization</b></th>\
              </tr>\
               <tr>\
            <td>".$user."</td>\
            <td>".$phone."</td>\
            <td>".$name."</td>\
            <td>".$mobile."</td>\
            </tr>\
            </table>);
            $(#myModal).modal({backdrop: false}); 
        }
        </script>";
```

Loop inside

```
$loop="";
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    $loop.="<tr><td>".$user."</td><td>".$phone."</td><td>".$name."</td><td>".$mobile."</td></tr>";
}
echo "<script>
        function myFunction(order){
            $('.modal-body').html(<table>\
            <tr>\
            <th><b>S.No</b></th>\
            <th><b>Name</b></th>\
            <th><b>Quantity</b></th>\
            <th><b>Personalization</b></th>\
              </tr>".$loop."</table>);
            $(#myModal).modal({backdrop: false}); 
        }
        </script>";
```

Comment: in their close double quote and give variable like(---".$user."---).

Comment: by using php concatenate. no need to use javascript one.

Comment: i updated the code how to use php variable inside check once.

Comment: now i a getting Sir, but one more thing is it possible to use a loop in the .html tag

Comment: Yes we can use. store all in one variable and display inside. I updated the code check once.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance Sir

Comment: welcome@DhruvTyagi, don't need to call sir. just use name.

Comment: Now i am struck at point is it possible to insert the SQL query into the javascript........
it means in my project i created a Modal and in the Modal  m added a button and as the button is click i have to send a query to my Database.....(the whole work is done through JavaScript)
is it possible or should i use onclick handler in my php

Comment: Use sql query before for loop and display values inside the loop in the variable of $root (like i mentioned in the above coding). then display it in inside the script.

Comment: Actually i did it but i shows error(means No output)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114216/discussion-between-mani-and-dhruv-tyagi).

Comment: My javascript Code:
** $('#click').click(function(){
      
          // $('#myModal').modal('hide')
    executeSql('SELECT * FROM pages');
       
       alert('hello');
      
       });**